# Add A tag to html table clickable event

Tags: c#, jquery, html

I have this table

which fills in c# as

```
foreach (Complains complainobj in lstrequest)
{
    info += @"<tr> ";
    info += @"<td '><strong>" + complainobj.ComplainId.ToString() + "</strong></td>";
    info += @"<td '><strong>" + donorname + "</strong></td>";
    info += @"<td '><strong> " + complainobj.ComplainDetails + "</strong></td>";
    info += @"<td '><strong>" + complainobj.ComplainTitle + "</strong></td>";
    info += @"<td '><div id='ComplainStatusID' style='float:right;display:block;'>"+
    "<strong>" + complainobj.ComplainStatus + "</strong></div>"+
    "<div id='ComplainStatusinputID' style='float:right;display:none;'>" +
    "<input id='editstatus' type='text'/></div>"
        + "<div style='float:left;'><a href='javascript:void(0)'  class='editstatusclass'> <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil'></span></a></td>";
    info += @"<td '><strong>" + complainobj.CompainNotes + "</strong></td>";
    info += @"<td '><strong>" + complaintype + "</strong></td>"; 
    info += @"</tr>";
}
```

When I add a tag as shown and try to handle it as

```
$("a.editstatusclass").on("click", function () {
   $("#ComplainStatusID").css('display', 'none');
   $("#ComplainStatusinputID").css('display', 'block');
});

$("#editstatus").blur(function () {
   var compainId = $(this).parent().parent().siblings(":first").text();
   alert(compainId)
});
```

it click the first row every time 
what I already need it to create a tag for every row and get html DATA ROW values

Comment: The apostophes (`'`) in your `td` elements may be causing issues in your code, you should remove them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $("a.editstatusclass").on("click", function () {
          //  $("#ComplainStatusID").css('display', 'none');
           // $("#ComplainStatusinputID").css('display', 'block');
              $(this).closest("tr").find("#ComplainStatusID").css('display', 'none');
           $(this).closest("tr").("#ComplainStatusinputID").css('display', 'block');

        });
```

Comment: this may work, but still you should not use id's in a loop. Id must be unique on a page, but here every row has an element with the same id. Try using `class` instead.